# Android Service starts/binds correctly, but only the first time

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that starts and binds correctly when it's first called, but successive bindings to that same service fail when called by other activities.

The code:

```
activity.startService(new Intent().setClass(activity, ServerListenerService.class));        

xmppServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            ServerActivityConnection.this.xmppService = null;
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
            //set everything up
        }
    };

activity.bindService(new Intent().setClass(activity, ServerListenerService.class), xmppServiceConnection, Activity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The second time around, after the call to `activity.bindService`, the serviceconnection's `onServiceConnected` method never gets called. I use a connection class that does the binding, so the method is the same for both activities. The service is also correctly added the manifest file.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Comment: If you have found the solution share it here as I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was related to `bindService()`.
I called it only once in `onResume()` - following some sample.

It seems that `bindService()` should be called each time you start service (with `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` in my case).